# How to maintain formatting of cells when copying cells from Excel to Word

Tags: c#, excel-2007, office-interop, word-2007

Currently I'm using `OleDB` to connect with Excel Spreadsheet and getting data in a `DataTable`, doing some modifications on data and then copying the data to Word.

In doing so I'm losing the formatting of the cell, like if any part of text was colored or if the background color was grayed or if it's bold.

I'm using Interop library to communicate with word and `OLEDB` with Excel.

If this solution is not good enough for what I need to achieve , can you suggest alternative solutions? (Macros?)
I tried using `Interop.Excel.Styles` but I can't figure out how to relate it with the cell being currently used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We copy the range of the table in the spreadsheet and the directly paste in the word document which preserves formatting.

```
wordDoc.Tables.Add(b.Range,newsheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count,newsheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table table = b.Range.Tables[1];
newsheet.UsedRange.Copy();
table.Range.Select(); 
wordApp.Selection.Paste();
```

wordDoc is Word.Document and wordApp is word.Application. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's gonna happen. OleDB moves data, not formatting information. If you want the formatting, you're going to have to copy/paste from Excel to Word. If you need to automate the process, VBA is the easiest way to control Excel and Word from the outside.

Comment: It is possible to move with Interop library with the formatting preserved, but as I need to perform certain manipulations I'm handicapped there.